# Does everything in the universe exist for amount of time in range of "0 - infinity" at the same time?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, time, relativity, time-dilation

Relativity principle says that **every moving object** experiences time differently, the faster you move the slower you age (the same goes for atoms, since everything is made out of them).

Consider this: There are pulsars rotating at **70,000 km/s**, which means all the atoms on the equator move at this speed, hence time moves slower for those atoms than it is for atoms in the solar system (**200 km/s** through galaxy) which means the half-life decay rate of those atoms would be different there (from every other possible perspective), which means they would exist for amount of time in range of 0 - infinity at the same time (for solar system's perspective decay rate of those atoms would be X, for another pulsar's perspective it would be Y, and as far as photons concerned half-life decay rate of atoms equals to 0)

So, does everything in the universe exist for amount of time in range of "0 - infinity" at the same time, depending on who is measuring? Is that really the case or there are logical mistakes in these statements?

Comment: Hi, I have an impression you mix 3 things : 1) special relativity (no, moving object does not experience time differently); 2) general relativity (gravity and other forces on pulsar,  i think there are nuclei, not atoms there) 3) philosophical question - can something exist forever, while not exist at all (=0) in other reference frame?

Comment: @jaromrax hi, well, I don't really care about infinity, let's make it a 10^10000 years instead. What I want to understand is if that's really how everything works in this universe. I'm just trying to understand relativity concept

Comment: Break up your question in around 3 parts and ask them one by one.

Comment: I think you're asking if all observers agree on the time since the Big Bang. Is so then the answer is no, and this question has been asked before though I can't lay my hands on a duplicate right now.